# Non-measurable set $A$ such that every measurable subset of $A$ or $A^c$ has measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to show the following:

> There is $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that both are satisfied:
>
> - if $E \subset A$ is a Lebesgue measurable set then $\lambda(E) = 0$
> - if $E \subset A^c$ is a Lebesgue measurable set then $\lambda(E) = 0$
>
> where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on the real line.

Do you know how to show that such a set exists? Also a reference would be appreciated. Thank you :)

ps: if you find a better title feel free to modify it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A standard construction goes by building the set by transfinite recursion to ensure that neither $A$ nor its complement contains a perfect set. Note that if this is the case, then any measurable subset of $A$ has measure $0$, because (by regularity of Lebesgue measure) if $E$ is measurable, $\lambda(E)$ is the supremum of $\lambda(K)$ for $K$ compact contained in $E$. But any compact set that has no perfect subset is in fact countable, so it has measure $0$. The same happens with $A^c$, but then neither $A$ nor $A^c$ can be measurable: If $A$ is measurable, then it has measure $0$, so $A^c$ has full measure and therefore contains a perfect set.

The transfinite recursion goes as follows: There are $\mathfrak c=|\mathbb R|$ many perfect subsets of $\mathbb R$. Identifying cardinals with ordinals, list them in a well-ordering of type $\mathfrak c$. We build $A$ and its complement by recursion. At stage $\alpha$ we have a set $A_{<\alpha}$ and a disjoint set $B_{<\alpha}$. (When $\alpha=0$, both are empty.) Consider the $\alpha$-th perfect set. Pick two elements of the perfect set not in $A_{<\alpha}\cup B_{<\alpha}$. Let $A_{\alpha}=A_{<\alpha+1}$ be the union of $A_{<\alpha}$ and one of these points, and let $B_{\alpha}$ be the union of $B_{<\alpha}$ and the other point. That the points exist follows from the fact that there are $\mathfrak c$ reals in any perfect set, but at stage $\alpha$ at most $2|\alpha|<\mathfrak c$ of them have been used. (When $\lambda$ is limit, $A_{<\lambda}$ is just the union of the previous $A_\alpha$, same for $B_{<\lambda}$.) At the end, one of the sets so built is $A$. This works, because by construction, given any perfect set $P$, at least one of its points is in $A$ (so $P$ is not contained in $A^c$), and at least one of its points is not (so $P$ is not contained in $A$).

The details of the construction can be varied a bit, but any argument must use choice in a nontrivial way, since it is [consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model) with the usual axioms of set theory (without the axiom of choice) that all sets of reals are measurable. That said, I haven't seen a presentation of the result I'm describing that avoids the use of a well-ordering of $\mathbb R$. The sets so obtained are called [Bernstein sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set), and were first exhibited by [Felix Berenstein](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Bernstein_Felix.html) (of [Bernstein-Schroeder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) fame) in $1908$.

Comment: Note that such a set is called a Bernstein set, and there have been [a](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169714/whats-application-of-bernstein-set) [bunch](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257328/constructing-a-bernstein-set-in-a-polish-space) [of](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393002/is-it-possible-that-the-union-of-a-bernstein-set-and-a-singleton-isnt-a-bernste) [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543499/bernstein-set-in-0-2) asked here about it already.

Comment: Yes, I should add a note mentioning the name.